# How to get touch location in Cocos2dx V3.8

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

`this->setTouchEnabled()` is deprecated.

This [link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/EventDispatcher_Mechanism) describes how to do it in V3, but `_eventDispatcher` seems to be deprecated now.

Does anyone know the correct way to handle touches in cocos2dx these days?

EDIT:

Currently using:

```
auto listener = cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
listener->setSwallowTouches(true);
listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(TouchableArea::touchOccoured, this);
this->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```

It works but I've no idea if this is the ideal though.

Comment: Do you want to get the touch location or disable touch input? your question title differs completely from the question itself.

Comment: I want to enable and use touches.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop/start separate event listener:

```
touchListener->setEnabled(false);
```

I checked now, it works fine. Cocos2d-x v.3.8.1.

EDIT:
I also don't know whether there is a better way. But in cpp-tests, NewEventDispatcherTest.cpp, class PauseResumeTargetTest, you can find these lines:

```
sprite3->getListener()->setEnabled(false);
_eventDispatcher->pauseEventListenersForTarget(this, true);
```

...

```
_eventDispatcher->resumeEventListenersForTarget(this, true);
sprite3->getListener()->setEnabled(true);
```

So, it will be an official way.